# Redirect "/" to "/home.html"

Tags: redirect, cpanel

How to  redirect  "/" to "/home.html" (i.e. the home page of website in Cpanel) ?

some thing like  if I type `iconlabs.com` it should redirect to `home.html` pesent in the root folder. I am uploading the content of my static site to CPanel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename home.html to index.html and you should be fine.

Comment: I did that.. and its working fine...  but is there a possibility that i can work with home.html  instead of index.html

Comment: Yes, you could add a .htaccess file to your site and include this line:

    `DirectoryIndex index.html home.html`

This tries first to use index.html and if that isn't found then use home.html

Comment: I'm of course assuming that the web server you're using is apache!